# Get value from div for PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table where I am using a select option and depending on the selection, through a script, which is provided below, a value appears in the following cell. My question is, how can I get the new appearing value in order to process it through php? For example, I select 'No' from the selection and in the next cell, the 'H' appears and I want to store the value of 'H'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Part of the table's code

```
<td>
    <select id="ynA4" name="ynA4">
        <option selected disabled hidden style="display: none" value=""></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="TBC">TBC</option>
        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <script>
        $('#ynA4').change(function() {
            opt = $(this).val();
            if (opt == "Yes") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('');
            } else if (opt == "No") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('H');
            } else if (opt == "TBC") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('');
            } else if (opt == "N/A") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('N/A');
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div id="hazardA4"></div>
</td>
```

**Solution: #1**

For example, if 'No' is selected and I want the 'H' to be stored, the script will be like this,

```
} else if (opt == "No") { $('#hazardA4').html('<input type="hidden" name="hazardA4" value="H">H');
```

**Solution: #2**

```
<script>
    var ynA4_val;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ynA4').change(function() {
            opt = $(this).val();
            if (opt == "Yes") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('');
                ynA4_val = '';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            } else if (opt == "No") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('H');
                ynA4_val = 'H';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            } else if (opt == "TBC") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('');
                ynA4_val = '';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            } else if (opt == "N/A") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('N/A');
                ynA4_val = 'N/A';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            }
        }); //END #ynA4.change
    }); //END document.ready
</script>
```

Comment: add a hidden input element, make sure its wrapped inside your form

Comment: Can you expand a little further? I've been playing with a hidden input element in the past couple of minutes but I can't get it work

Comment: just add a hidden input, just modify the value attribute inside the change block of your select

Comment: Ok, what I changed in the jquery is what appears after the selection, for example
 } else if (opt == "No") { $('#hazardA4').html('<input type="text" name="hazardA4" value="H">');  and a textbox appears with the 'H' value inside it, if it had the hidden attribute the 'H' wouldn't appear. This is my partial solution, can you suggest something better?

Comment: I feel like an idiot, solved it with, } else if (opt == "No") { $('#hazardA4').html('<input type="hidden" name="hazardA4" value="H">H'); Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the `<script>` code in a document ready, or the script might fire and attempt to bind the `change` event to an element that doesn't yet exist in the DOM.

If you have only one form on the page, this will work. Else, replace `$('form')` with `$('#yourFormID')`

```
<script>
    var ynA4_val;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ynA4').change(function() {
            opt = $(this).val();
            if (opt == "Yes") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('');
                ynA4_val = '';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="ynA4" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            } else if (opt == "No") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('H');
                ynA4_val = 'H';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="ynA4" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            } else if (opt == "TBC") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('');
                ynA4_val = '';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="ynA4" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            } else if (opt == "N/A") {
                $('#hazardA4').html('N/A');
                ynA4_val = 'N/A';
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="ynA4" value="' +ynA4_val+ '" />');
            }
        }); //END #ynA4.change
    }); //END document.ready
</script>
```

Note that there are now two ways to get at that information:

(1) Via the hidden form element posted with the form: `$sumthin = $_POST['ynA4']`

(2) Via the global variable `ynA4_val` in javascript, which you can add to the data being sent over AJAX.

(3) UPDATE: Note that I neglected to put a `name="varname"` attribute in the original answer. Fixed/Updated.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

From the suggestion of @Ghost ,
For example, if 'No' is selected and I want the 'H' to be stored, the script will be like this,

```
} else if (opt == "No") { $('#hazardA4').html('<input type="hidden" name="hazardA4" value="H">H');
```